# Explain the Terms: Semantically Richer and Spatially More Precise in the HRNet Model Paper

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation, deep-learning

High-resolution representations are essential for position-sensitive vision problems, such as human pose estimation, semantic segmentation, and object detection.
From **HR-Nets** we get semantically richer and spatially more precise resultant, what does this statement mean in the paper [Deep High Resolution Representation Learning for Visual Recognition](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.07919).

Comment: Could you review my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model task is [semantic segmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_segmentation).
So for each pixel we assign a class.

In this context:

1. Semantically Richer
   Being able to detect more classes accurately.
2. More Precise
   Means the boundary between classes instances is more accurate. So spatially the segmentation is more accurate.

To give a concrete example:

[image]

Richer means you can see more colors, as more classes are identified.
Precise means the edges between the classes matches the edges in the real world image.